# Send and receive images using Flask

Tags: python, http, web, flask

Currently I support sending 1 image per request like so:

```
img_b64 = fileToB64(img)

return {
    'base64': [{
        'name': 'img',
        'contentType': 'image/png'
    }],
    'img': img_b64
}
```

But I need to implement new feature than enables to send any number of images (usually 1 but max 4 images) per request. Is there an easy way to send list of images? Sth like this:

```
img_b64s = [fileToB64(img) for img in images]
return {
    'base64': [{
        'name': 'img',
        'contentType': 'image/png'
    }],
    'imgs': img_b64s
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to modify your data-structures to accommodate this.  Maybe a table/document in your database that has a record of all the pictures for whatever criteria.  Then just send that.